# Require password to wake computer by specific condition

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login, screen-lock

I'd like to require password to wake my Macbook Air running Mavericks when it is not in my home.

So if it was not connected to my home wifi, then I'd like it to require password to wake from sleep or screen saver. And else, I'd like it to require password.

Can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com):

1. Add a context named home from the contexts tab.
2. Enable the nearby WiFi network evidence source from the evidence sources tab.
3. Go to the rules tab and add a nearby WiFi network rule that sets the context to home.
4. Add two screen saver password actions from the actions tab:

[image]

Another option is to add a line like this to crontab:

`* * * * * system_profiler SPAirPortDataType|grep -q 'network name'&&x=false||x=true;osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell security preferences to set require password to wake to '$x`

Comment: The only step I needed to add was: 1.5. In the Evidence Sources tab, enable Nearby WiFi Network in order to enable to create a rule based on that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This won't work since MacOS Sierra. From their website: `For that reason, a future version of ControlPlane will remove the screensaver password action and other actions that no longer work on macOS Sierra because of various security updates within the OS. I know some people use ControlPlane specifically for that feature but at this point ControlPlane can’t continue to say it can do it when it in fact cannot.`

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, this cannot be done.